# Get string after '/' character in SQL Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I get all numbers after slash in my column?
Example: `884/9` and `884/12`
I need to get it as "9" and "12".

This one doesn't work - I am using Postgres and Dibi library

```
substring(source_path, '/(.*)$')
```

Comment: why doens't it work? Please provide sample results. Also what postgres version do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have only one `/` on your data, and it is always formatted similar to the example you gave, then you can use `SPLIT_PART()` :

```
SELECT split_part(source_path, '/', 2) FROM YourTable;
```

Although I think your query should work. What exactly 'doesn't work' means ?

Comment: Doesn't work means = Unknown syntax at  regular `'/(.*)$'`. As I know, the number 2 in your code means it returns 2 chars right? I will have only one '/' but I will have N chars after it.

Comment: No, it will return all chars after it. @jax-p